# ASP.NET Rewrite Rule with hash bang

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, web-config, url-rewrite-module

I have an incoming route that looks like the following:

http://localhost:6553/account/activate?token=something

and i want to rewrite it to the following

http://localhost:6553/#/account/activate?token=something

how would this look in my web.config with an outbound rewrite rule?

thanks!